Fasting with a medical condition
My wife suffers from debilitating migraine headaches that cause vomiting and require medications and hours of bed rest in a dark room to recover. She has reached middle age and her condition is aggravated by fasting. She is very stubborn and insists on some sort of Rabbinical authorization in order not to fast when required by a particular holiday. Whom could I contact for such a thing or is there another way to prove to her that her health comes first?

You should speak with your local rabbinical authority (especially if he has any medical background).

For cases of practical ruling, ask a competent rabbinic authority.

The Mishneh Berurah (551:4) rules unequivocally that a choleh/sick person - even a choleh she'ein lo sakanah/ non life-threatening condition - is exempt from fasting [the four fasts, not including Yom Kippur], and indeed forbidden to fast.

וכל שכן אם הוא חולה שאין בו סכנה, בוודאי פטור מלהתענות, ואסור לו
להחמיר על עצמו

However, the rules for Yom Kippur are different. Nothing less than pikuach nefesh [or safek pikuach nefesh] would allow eating or drinking on Yom Kippur. Speak to a competent medical practitioner and then a competent halachic authority to ascertain whether a specific medical condition constitutes a safek pikuach nefesh.

As was pointed out, the fast of Yom Kippur is Biblical in its requirement,
and very strict, while he fast of 9th of Av is Rabbinical in nature but still strict, while other fasts are even more lenient et.
The truth is that it is correct for you and your wife to have a Rabbi who is knowlegable in Torah Law to guide you.
If you have no one that personally connects with you and your needs in your community, you might ask your doctor about it, and also call this resource to speak with a Rabbi and talk it over:
https://kavhalacha.org/medical-halacha/
May your wife become well from any trace of migraines and be able to enjoy life.
